# Server name not shown on SQL Server 2016 after installation (installation in Azure VM)

Tags: installation, sql-server-2016, azure-virtual-machine

I am trying to install SQL Server 2016 on Azure VM (Windows Server 2019 Datacenter), and I am having an issue with **server name not shown** (in SQL Server 2016).

[image]

I used bottom file to install manually, and thing is when I tried to install, it did not ask for anything like (Server name).

[image]

The reason that I am installing version 2016 is because our vendor only goes with 2016 version.

It said "installation complete" after I clicked the set up file.

One thing I noticed is there is no folder created for this particular server name:

[image]

Nothing here:
[image]

When I typed . bottom error message shows up:

[image]

What might be the issue?

Comment: Just type `.` for the server name. Tell your vendor to jump, 2016 is already on extended support

Comment: @Charlieface  I just added an image (updated content) when I typed . Thanks.

Comment: Please confirm if there is a Windows service installed called MSSQLSSERVER / SQL Server. Check also in SQL Server Configuration Manager as to what the name of the instance is

Comment: @Charlieface Where do I check? In Azure?

Comment: Yes, in the VM. To be honest looking at your screenshot again: seems you never actually installed SQL Server, only SSMS. Of the two installation files you show, the top one is the actual database engine.

Comment: @Charlieface Ok. my bad. I am doing it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to install SQL Server. I only installed SSMS.